# Bad Request: line 1:115 mismatched input ';' expecting K_VALUES in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have created a table in Cassandra using cqsql

```
CREATE TABLE UnderTest (
rowID  text PRIMARY KEY,
secondID  text ,
Start_Time  timestamp,
End_Time  timestamp,
Exp  int,
Act  int,
Reason text 
);
```

and now i am inserting data into table using insert command like this:

```
insert into UnderTest values ('1','A1','2011-02-03 04:05+0000','2011-02-03 05:05+0000','2011-02-03 06:08+0000','COMM');
```

in this i am getting error :

```
Bad Request: line 1:115 mismatched input ';' expecting K_VALUES
```

any help??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am a new bee in Cassandra and forgot to mention the column name in the insert after inserting the names problem resolved.

Now the query is like this

```
insert into UnderTest (rowID,secondID,Start_Time,End_Time,Exp,Act,Reason) 
values ('1','ATM1','2011-02-03 04:05+0000','2011-02-03 05:05+0000',3600,4200,'COMM') ;
```